# Subtract amount of shipping class from total cart and then apply free shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

Brief: Subtract amount from a certain shipping class from total amount, then check if Free shipping value is met.

Long:
I need some guidance in how I should accomplish this. I have 3 items in a shipping class called "Heavy". And I have free shipping if you reach the amount of 500. However, the "heavy" class should never be calculated in the free shipping as it got it's own shipping. The Heavy class cost 200.

Example:
If you buy for 300 normal goods, + heavy for 200. The total amount is 500. Here the shipping for the 300 + the heavy goods should be applied, even though the total amount is Freeshipping-approved.

Example 2:
You buy normal goods for 500 and heavy for 200. Free shipping is applied for the 500, shipping rate is applied for the 200.

I am using WooComerce table rate shipping, if that helps at all.

Thanks.

Comment: It's complicated as you can't have at the same time Free shipping method enabled for some items and a flat rate applied for others. How are set your flat rates… can you give more details about your shipping zones and the rates amounts that are applied.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I got 3 classes, and loads of different flatrates depending on different values. I just need that one special class to be excluded from free shipping.

Comment: I should need all possible details as this need to be done manually in the code when other items total is 500 or more with at least a "heavy" item in cart… So try to give all possible details updating your question (with all the shipping methods IDS too)